# Convert Laravel array collection to array

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

I was updating may images array which is found in following format:

```json
[
    "d756d3d2b9dac72449a6a6926534558a.jpg",
    "b607aa5b2fd58dd860bfb55619389982.jpg", 
    "f937c8fddbe66ab03c563f16d5cfa50c.jpg"
]
```

So to delete a single image `d756d3d2b9dac72449a6a6926534558a.jpg` from this array column I used the `filter` method like below:

```
$collection = collect($imageColumn)->filter(
    function ($valueTobeDeleted) use ($array) {
        return !in_array($valueTobeDeleted, $array);
    }
);
```

so after filter I wan to update my database with the new collection, but the new collection is in a map format like below

```
array:2 [
    1 => "b607aa5b2fd58dd860bfb55619389982.jpg"
    2 => "f937c8fddbe66ab03c563f16d5cfa50c.jpg"
]
```

the problem is i don't need those keys 1, and 2 my expectation was

```
array:2 [
    "b607aa5b2fd58dd860bfb55619389982.jpg"
    "f937c8fddbe66ab03c563f16d5cfa50c.jpg"
]
```

How can I achieve my expectation? How can I convert them to array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a Collection, you can do [`->values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values) at the end so you convert all keys into integer keys and beginning from 0, like a normal non-associative array:

```php
$collection = collect($imageColumn)->filter(
    function ($valueTobeDeleted) use ($array) {
        return !in_array($valueTobeDeleted, $array);
    }
)
    ->values();
```

Comment: @Khal remember to always check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods), so you know what methods you have available and what does each one do. Just make suer to select the correct Laravel version

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-index an array, you can use the `array_values` PHP function:

```php
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

This will fix the keys.

Answer (score -1):

Use array_values to get a an array of that associatve array.

```php
$collection = collect($imageColumn)->

$filtered = filter(function ($valueTobeDeleted) use ($array) {
  
    return !in_array($valueTobeDeleted, $array);
});

$filtered = array_values($filtered);
```